# Safari - createMediaElementSource not working?

Tags: safari, web-audio-api

I like to add audio panning effect to Youtube.

But I found web audio api works in Chrome but not in Safari (v.13.1 on MacOS 10.15.4)

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open Youtube Video in Safari
2. Open the dev console and paste the following code

```js
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "Pan";
    button.style.position = "fixed"
    button.style.backgroundColor = "#0C9"
    button.style.bottom = "20px"
    button.style.right = "20px"
    button.style.fontSize = "24px"

    document.body.appendChild(button);

    let audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);
    const videoElement = document.querySelector('video');

    button.onclick = () => {
        console.log("== onclick ==")
        const source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(videoElement);
        var panner = audioCtx.createPanner();
        panner.panningModel = 'equalpower';
        panner.setPosition(-1, 0, 0);

        source.connect(panner);
        panner.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    };
```

3. Click the Pan button

It should pan the audio to the left. But it didn't work in Safari.

The action is [triggered by user click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36430194/webkitaudiocontext-createmediaelementsource-on-ios-safari-not-working/52621878#52621878) and it doesn't violate the [cross-origin restriction](https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#MediaElementAudioSourceOptions-security).

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

In short:

**createMediaElementSource is not working on streaming source in Safari.**

According to this thread 
[Possible to analyze streaming audio from Icecast using Web Audio API and createMediaElementSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271257/possible-to-analyze-streaming-audio-from-icecast-using-web-audio-api-and-createm)

I tested:

- case 1: streaming source with cors issue => mute sound
- case 2: streaming source with correct cors => play the sound but no data from the source node.

I also tested the static file as source case. Safari is worked correctly.